# How to get instagram username from new facebook graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, instagram, instagram-api

Looking at the new Instagram Graph API - there is no direct way to retrieve `username` once a user is logged in. Although it says in the official document that a call like

```
 "https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/17841405822304914?fields=biography%2Cid%2Cusername%2Cwebsite&access_token=EAACwX..."
```

should return the following:

```
{
  "biography": "Dino data crunching app",
  "id": "17841405822304914",
  "username": "metricsaurus",
  "website": "http://www.metricsaurus.com/"
}
```

This currently returns an error, and looks like there is no such option to get only **username** of an instagram business user.

[image]

Comment: What’s the error?

Comment: The error is "(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (instagram_business_account) on node type (User)"

Comment: With the request as you have shown it? Where you are not even asking for that field …?

Comment: @04FS also this one: message: "(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (biography) on node type (User)"
Really tried everything, but looks like FB api got really redundant and not up to date on the official website

Comment: Please link to the documentation section that you are referring to.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/user#metadata
The question is very simple - I just need to take the IG username of a logged in user, really nothing works

Comment: And your access token includes the required permissions?

Comment: of course.. it has all

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about fetching username of an instagram business account which is linked to your facebook page, you can use the below curl

```
curl -i -X GET "https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/me/accounts?fields=instagram_business_account%7Busername%2Cname%2Cig_id%7D&access_token=<access_token>"
```

Please replace access_token with your user access token in the above curl.

Sample reponse which you will get for the above curl is as below :

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "instagram_business_account": {
        "username": "<instagram user name>",
        "name": "<instagram display name>",
        "id": "<corresponding facebook graph id for instagram profile>",
        "ig_id": <instagram profile id>
      },
      "id": "<facebook page id>"
    }
  ],
  "paging": {
    "cursors": {
      "before": "MTc2Njg1MTU2MTI1ODA1",
      "after": "OTg3MzU1NzExNDUwMDg3"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If it helps to someone.. Now its better to do it like this GrapAPI v10.0

```
 FB.api('/' + pageID + '?fields=instagram_business_account{id,name,username}',
     function (response) {
        // TODO: whatever you want
     },
     { access_token: accessToken }
 );
```

EDIT: I wouldn't do it this way anymore. Its very old code, I would wrap it somehow and I am not sure this still works..

Answer (score -1):

I was able to solve this only by using the [old api](https://www.instagram.com/developer/).

According to their documentation, although the old API is about to become deprecated, as of now, it is meant for small businesses or personal apps. 
The new [Instagram Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/) is "An API for accessing data in large- and medium-sized Instagram Business Accounts"

Looks like FB doensn't know it's way around.